# How to disable Gmail anti-spam completely?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I'm using a desktop client with my own configured spam filter, and I'm absolutely unhappy with Gmail server side anti-spam, as it makes too many false-positives. How can I disable it? I've tried setting up filter for all letters with an action set to "Never send it to Spam", but some letters still are sent to the Spam folder by Gmail. Any other ways?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think a Gmail user can completely opt-out of the server-side anti-spam protection. I believe this may be possible for Google Apps users, but I've not looked into this.

Answer (score 30):

The following steps will find e-mail that Gmail marks as spam and prevent it from going to the Spam "folder". This will then allow your your desktop client to download the e-mail and perform the spam filtering. This type of arrangement is often necessary if spammers send out e-mail using keywords that are legitimate for certain industries such as e-commerce, finance, pharmaceuticals, sex, or gambling.

Anyway, the Gmail steps are:

- On the upper right, go to **Gear** icon > **Settings**

[image: Settings]

- Go to Filters tab

[image: Filters tab]

- Click **Create a new filter** at the bottom

[image: create a new filter]

- In the `Has the words` field, enter `is:spam`
- Click **Create filter with this search**

[image]

- Click **OK**

[image]

- Check on **Never Send it to Spam**
- Click on **Create Filter**

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer to a stupid flaw on Google's part. The spam filter took out a very important email, and I didn't see it. Thanks, I did this just now.

Comment: It seems to help a bit, but some letters still go to the Spam folder.

Comment: Try adding a couple of more filters (that are also set to never go to spame); one that flags any message that contains a `@` in the `From` (essentially *all* emails), and another that flags any messages that are `>0 bytes` (again, essentially *all* emails). You can also make one that flags any messages that have a `@` in the `To` field (ostensibly, your email address has one), and another to send flag any messages that are `<1 bytes` to cover any magical, empty messages.

Comment: A WARNING. If you use your gmail account primarily as a forwarding account (to forward all mail to a different account), DO NOT DISABLE THE SPAM FILTER as described in this answer. Your account will start forwarding spam and may be suspended by Google as a result.

Comment: Would be nice but web interface still annoys with `this messages would go to spam` notification... Any ideas how to hide it?

Comment: FYI, I just ran the "is:spam" search and gmail auto-changed it to "in:spam".

Comment: The answer is not correct. You are ignoring the warning: "they will never match incoming mail".

Comment: I wrote the answer six years ago. Has something changed for you?

Comment: @smudge Did that happen to you? How many spam emails were forwarded? Did you manage to re-enable it?

Comment: Yes, this does not work.  (Maybe it did once?)  Will try the From contains @ trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the Google help pages, and I think if you follow the instructions you will be able to do it:

> Sign in to the Google Admin console.
>
> From the dashboard, go to Google Apps > Gmail > Advanced settings.
>
> In the Organizations section, highlight your domain or the organizational unit for which you want to configure settings (see Configure advanced settings for Gmail for more details).
>
> Scroll down to the Spam section:
>
> If the setting's status is Not configured yet, click Configure (the "Add setting" dialog box displays).
>
> If the setting's status is Locally applied, click Edit to edit an existing setting (the "Edit setting" dialog box displays), or click Add another to add a new setting (the "Add setting" dialog box displays).
>
> If the setting’s status is Inherited, click View to view the inherited setting, or click Add another to add a new setting (the "Add setting" dialog box displays).
>   Enter a description for this configuration—for example, "Eng Spam Bypass Setting."
>
> To turn on more aggressive bulk mail spam filters, check the Be more aggressive when filtering bulk mail box.
>
> To set up an approved sender list, select either or both of the following options:
>   To bypass spam filters for messages received from internal senders (from users in the same organization), select the Bypass spam filters for messages received from internal senders option.
>
> To bypass spam filters for messages received from addresses or domains specified in your approved sender lists, select the Bypass spam filters for messages received from addresses or domains within these approved senders lists option.
>
> If you checked the second box in step 7, do the following:
>
> Click Add or create a new one to create a new approved sender list.
>
> To use an existing list as your approved sender list, click the list name.
>
> To create a new list, enter a name for the list in the Create new list field, and then click Create.
>
> To edit one of your lists, hover over the list name, click Edit, and then do any of the following:
>
> To add email addresses or domains to the list, click Add.
>
> Enter an email address or domain name (for example, solarmora.com).
>
> Note: Check the Do not require sender authentication box to bypass the spam folder for approved senders that do not have authentication, such as SPF or DKIM enabled. Use this option with caution as it can potentially lead to spoofing.
>
> When you're finished making changes, click Add setting or Save to close the dialog box.
>   Repeat these steps to add more email addresses or domains to the list.
>   When you're finished making changes, click Add Setting to close the dialog box.
>
> Note: Any settings you add will be highlighted on the "Email settings" page.
>   Click Save changes at the bottom of the "Email settings" page

[Source](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368132?hl=en).

Comment: To be clear on this one, the first part mentioned, the admin console, is only available to organization-level administrators. End users who are not admins do not have this option.

Comment: And now it's not changing it from "is" to "in". Odd.